# A word meaning discord between the phonology of a word and its meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

The word 'lauded' always gets to me, because I instinctively consider it to hold the opposite denotation. Is there a specific word for a word that holds that (completely subjective) quality?

Comment: what do you mean by "opposite connotation?" what is it that you misconstrue "lauded" to be?

Comment: It's not a matter of misconstruing so much as I don't think the sound of the word or the appearance fits the meaning, not the connotation.

Comment: What could be influencing you to "instinctively consider it to hold the opposite denotation" -- you may be associating the sound of the word with something depending on past experience. That's not for the language to answer for.

Comment: enervate? temerity?

Comment: Oh, that's definitely likely. Hence 'completely subjective' and 'think.' I was just curious to know if there was a word that described this sensation. It's not at all a matter of an inanimate concept having something 'to answer for' as it is 'does this means of expression have an outlet for this feeling?'